# Include/package external libraries with my library

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, android-volley

I am creating my own Android library, let's call it MyLibrary.jar
My library is referencing volley.jar (and several others). Now in order to use my library clients have to add volley.jar to their APK project together with MyLibrary.jar

How can I package my library together with volley.jar, so that my users do not bother about extra dependencies? I am using Eclipse.

UPDATE:
I added Volley source files to MyLibrary project and now MyLibrary.jar file contains Volley, but it kind of ugly solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a soft link from the `libs` folder of your desired library jar. To do it in Eclipse right-click on the `libs` folder and choose `New ... -> File -> Advanced` Check `Link to file in the filesystem` and point it to to your volley.jar. This should do the trick.

To make sure that volley.jar is always updated select it as a `Referenced Project` in `Project Properties` of your library